# What seat is the best overall seat in an American football stadium?

Tags: american-football

Sitting front row at the 50 yard line gives a spectator an intense (and expensive) view of a small focal point of an American football field.

Sitting higher up gives a spectator a better overall field view, but keeps a fan from enjoying the full violence of the game.

Sitting in the corner gives a great view of a single endzone, but the opposite endzone can appear a mile away, and your team (presuming you have one) will only score in that endzone during a single half (which a ticket buyer cannot predict prior to the coinflip).

**With all this in mind, what seat in the average American football stadium offers the best overall view? What about best view for one's buck?**

Comment: This seems awfully subjective.

Comment: I dunno, if you provide reasons, it is less subjective.  Also, assuming no other obstructions, right?

Comment: I'm mostly thinking about geometry here and how a spectator in a stadium can best view a sport that utilizes a 2D space in a particular way. Maybe it's less subjective with this in mind?

Comment: I still see that as 'bad subjective'. It meets five of the six guidelines of 'good subjective' but misses "Great subjective questions insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references." It's going to be difficult to find some kind of non-opinion related references.

Comment: Subjective opinions almost always have reasons, that doesn't make them any less subjective -- it's all about prioritization of criteria, which is what makes it subjective.

Comment: where the owners and special guests seat would be a good guess to this

Answer (score 4):

As wax eagle stated, this is an extremely subjective question and really depends on what your'e there to see. That being said...

For the average fan, I would say the best seat would be the 50 yard line, 10 to 20 rows back. It gives the centre location that will allow you to see as much of the potential play as possible, and the distance back from the field will allow you to have a better view of the field as the plays are executed, instead of the backs of the players.

Comment: Agreed. Teams seem to think so too - the most expensive seats in NFL stadiums (other than the luxury boxes) tend to be in the section between the two 40-yard lines.